How to force the border with in the rectangle with `\filldraw`?
As the title describes, I would like to force the border that \filldraw created not to exceed the filled area, just like the following figure.

However, calculating the width of the border directly just like the following MWE is so awful, is there an elegant method?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [blue!10] (0,0) rectangle + (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1ex]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw [line width = 6pt, draw = black, fill = blue!10] (0,0) rectangle + (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1ex]

How to force the border with in the rectangle? Such as\\[1ex]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw [line width = 6pt, draw = black, fill = blue!10] (0,0) rectangle + ({2cm-5pt},{2cm-5pt});
\end{tikzpicture}\\[1ex]

\end{document}


You can draw a border twice as thick and then crop to the rectangle.

you can use \pgflinewidth/2 in many, but not all, cases so you needn't hard code the width. you could also use outer sep, for example, but that will have side-effects you might not want. in general, I would say this is just how the programme works. if you explain the context, it should be possible to give possibly more helpful suggestions, but it is tricky in the abstract because any particular method will have untoward effects in some cases.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that's a good suggestion, though it will have unwanted effects in some cases. (but I think any method will.)

you can also fill rather than draw the border e.g. by filling a larger rectangle or by using the alternate filling rule with two closed paths.

Q was about PSTricks but here's a TikZ approach via nfold: A133670 which applies to all segments of a path. – You only adjust the second corner of the rectangle but not the first. Do you only want the left and right side to squeeze or all sides? Otherwise, you'd need ([xshift=.5\pgflinewidth, yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]0,0) and ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth, yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]2,2). You shouldn't mix canvas coordinates (with a unit) with xyz coordinates (without a unit) that's why I'm using a shift transformation.

off-topic: don't use \\  for paragraph/line breaks in ordinary contexts.
